# While loop to print out every character but "C" in the string

Tags: python

I need to write a while loop that iterates through an entire string, but skips all the C's in the string. My current code just runs forever, and I can't get any sort of traceback because of it.

Here's what I have right now:

```
DNA = 'GTTGATGTAGCTTATATAAAGCAAGGCACTGAAAATGCCTAGATGAGTCATAGACTCCATAAACAACAGGTTTGGTCCCGGC'
x = 0
Part2 = []
while(x < len(DNA)):
  if DNA[x] != 'C':
    Part2.append(DNA[x])
    x = x + 1
  else:
    continue
print("Part 2: ", Part2)
```

Comment: THere's no need for `else: continue`. Loops automatically continue unless you break out of them.

Comment: Please try to explain the loop to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially, when you get to a `'C'`, be very detailed when and how you increment `x`.

Comment: Why not just use `for char in DNA:` instead of the problematic `while` loop?

Comment: Why do you "need" to write a while loop? Also, are you sure you want to print a list?

Answer (score 4):

This can be much simpler:

```
print([c for c in DNA if c != 'C'])
```

Or, if you want a string:

```
print(''.join([c for c in DNA if c != 'C']))
```

A similar approach (proposed by @Barmar):

```
print(DNA.replace('C', ''))
```

Comment: Alternatively, `print(''.join(filter(lambda x: x != 'C', DNA)))`

Answer (score 1):

Your `else:continue` blocks the counter `x` from advancing:

```py
DNA = 'GTTGATGTAGCTTATATAAAGCAAGGCACTGAAAATGCCTAGATGAGTCATAGACTCCATAAACAACAGGTTTGGTCCCGGC'
x = 0
Part2 = []
while(x < len(DNA)):
  if DNA[x] != 'C':
    Part2.append(DNA[x])
  x = x + 1
print("Part 2: ", Part2)
```

I removed that and unindented the increment.

You should consider using simpler code as has been posted already.

Comment: The `else:continue` doesn't block the loop from *advancing*. Rather, what happens is that when the `else` condition is met, `x` doesn't increment, and `DNA[x]` is stuck at its last value, which is `'C'`, so the `else` condition is met permanently, leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: @jjramsey: Ok, fixed the description. I was too loose with my terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you said you need to use a while loop...

```py
dna = 'GTTGATGTAGCTTATATAAAGCAAGGCACTGAAAATGCCTAGATGAGTCATAGACTCCATAAACAACAGGTTTGGTCCCGGC'
x = 0
Part2 = []
while(x < len(dna)):
    if dna[x] != 'C':
        Part2.append(dna[x])
    else:
        pass
    x += 1

print("Part 2: ", Part2)
```

Alternatively, you can change `Part2` to be a string, for the sake of readability at the end. I also removed the `else: pass` section as it isn't necessary to run the code.

```py
dna = 'GTTGATGTAGCTTATATAAAGCAAGGCACTGAAAATGCCTAGATGAGTCATAGACTCCATAAACAACAGGTTTGGTCCCGGC'
x = 0
Part2 = ''
while(x < len(dna)):
    if dna[x] != 'C':
        Part2 += dna[x]
    x += 1

print("Part 2: ", Part2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need `Part2` as a list, you can also use `list()` function. (or remove `list()` for string output as [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) and [@Riccardo Bucco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73790396/19574157) suggested)

```
DNA = 'GTTGATGTAGCTTATATAAAGCAAGGCACTGAAAATGCCTAGATGAGTCATAGACTCCATAAACAACAGGTTTGGTCCCGGC'
Part2 = list(DNA.replace('C', ''))
print("Part 2: ", Part2)
```